# Skip screen in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am trying to create a dynamic splash screen in the app, for that I have created a component screen called `Splashscreen` and after a certain interval I am routing the user to the normal stack. The problem is when the user is navigating back I do not want the user to reach the splash screen before being able to exit the app.

This is my code so far

```
const NewsStack = StackNavigator({
    . . . 
});

export const Root = StackNavigator({
    Splashscreen: {
        screen: Splashscreen
    },
    Mainscreen: {
        screen: NewsStack
    }
}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

The `NewsStack` is what contains the rest of the app. As of now the app works fine by opening the splashscreen and then navigating a different screen after a certain timeout but while navigating out of the app the user reaches the splashscreen. Is there any way other than listening for back button press? Does the back button method work in iOS as well?

Answer (score 3):

Use switchnavigator as documented in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html

— from the docs

> The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a
>   time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes
>   to their default state when you switch away

—

By default it handles the back button

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned `SwitchNavigator` is a good option. But you can get it done simply by conditional rendering instead of pushing Splash Screen to navigation stack. Since lots of answers are available on this I am simply pasting a link to a similar one so as to avoid duplication.
[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273057/show-splash-screen-before-show-main-screen-in-react-native-without-using-3rd-par?rq=1)